# split column with long strings into 1 word per row sql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I've seen similar questions around stackoverflow, yet none deal speecifically with just 1 column  --- I have a column in which there are multiple words per row.  I set up the rows so that the words are separated by #'s.  I now want it so that the strings are parsed and there is only one word per row.  Here is what the column currently looks like (about 1500 rows currently):

```
TEST
 ---------------------------------------------
 SPOKE#WITH#MR#SMITHS#ASSISTANT
 MRS#MOODY#REFUSED#A#VISIT
 SCHEDULING#OFFICE#LEFT#A#MESSAGE#FOR#VISIT
 LEFT#A#MESSAGE#FOR#VISIT
 SCHEDULING#OFFICE#SCHEDULED#AN#APPOINTMENT#FOR#DR#JOHNSON
 PHONE#CALL
 ---------------------------------------------
```

and i would like it to look something like this:

```
TEST
-------------------
SPOKE
WITH
MR
SMITHS
ASSISTANT
MRS
MOODY
REFUSED
A
VISIT
SCHEDULING
OFFICE
LEFT
etc... etc... etc...
-------------------
```

I'm relatively new to this type of query so any tutorials or documentation you could point me towards would also be helpful.  I'm using TOAD with OracleSQL.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in the realm of Oracle `PL/SQL` there is a useful set of functions called `REGULAR EXPRESSIONS`.  Splitting delimited strings into smaller strings fits under the category of the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function, as in the following example:

> **EDIT:** Spotted an oversight:  The last number in the delimited series is left out of the output.  The number of delimiters is 1 less than the number of elements in the series... the number of `LOOP` iterations has been updated.

**The Query Demo**

```
 DECLARE
   x varchar2(100);
   y pls_integer;
   z pls_integer;
   c VARCHAR2(40) := '1:3:4:6:8:10:3:4:7:6:11:12';
 BEGIN
   y := length(c) - length(replace(c,':'));  
   if y > 0 then
      for z in 1 .. (y+1) loop
      x := REGEXP_SUBSTR(c,'[^:]+', 1, z);
      dbms_output.put_line(x);

      end loop;
      x :- REGEXP_SUBSTR(c,'[
   end if;
 end;
```

**The Output:**

```
 1
 3
 4
 6
 8
 10
 3
 4
 7
 6
 11

 Statement processed.

 0.01 seconds
```

**Using the Example of the OP**

```
      DECLARE
        cursor str_cursor is
           select string_val
             from test_split_string;

        x varchar2(100);
        y pls_integer;
        z pls_integer;
      BEGIN
        for n in str_cursor loop
           y := length(n.string_val) - length(replace(n.string_val,'#'));  
           for z in 1 .. (y+1) loop       
              x := REGEXP_SUBSTR(n.string_val,'[^#]+', 1, z);
              dbms_output.put_line(x);
           end loop;
        end loop;
      end;
```

**Results from Example 2**

```
 MRS
 MOODY
 REFUSED
 A
 SCHEDULING
 OFFICE
 LEFT
 A
 MESSAGE
 FOR
 LEFT
 A
 MESSAGE
 FOR
 SPOKE
 WITH
 MR
 ETC... ETC... ETC...
```

A search on the term `ORACLE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS` should yield some good web resources to document additional features available.

Comment: very detailed, thank you...  i guess i was most confused with how to create a new row for each word, and i didn't realize you could use common programming syntax to create logic... ill have to do some research on writing these types of macros

Comment: Thanks!  I suppose I (cheated) a little since you probably were trying to approach the problem under the constraints of the `SQL` programming language.  This snippet would probably be a little longer if done in pure SQL... which is still possible... just messy.  Since you're working in the `ORACLE` environment, there is the possibility of using Oracle's custom extension to SQL (which is `PL/SQL`) which allows the use of procedural logic and processing steps to the standard database query language capabilities.  Enjoy!